# Weblogic console safe-mode

Tags: console, weblogic

I have a Weblogic server running in production mode with a deployed application. There is an error in my application and so when launching Weblogic after startup process it goes to shutdown. Is there any way of starting Weblogic with the deployed application in stopped mode? I just want to be able to connect to Weblogic console so I was just wondering if there is any safe-mode option.

Oracle Welogic version: 10.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do:

As a workaround if you are stuck completely - temporarily comment out the `app-deployment` section of your `<domain>/config/config.xml` file just to get the server back up. Or just move the deployment out of the `autodeploy` directory.

Another option for when you deploy your application, use the `distributeApplication` method, which will copy the deployment to the specified targets but not start it. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1260412